# Create custom server

Tags: sql, arrays, database, data-structures

love the data and how sorted and process, and how can controlled.
I wanna to know if can build own server, and how can upload the data in it.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the type of data that you want to store.

Assuming you simply want to upload and store files on a server, then you can consider using [minio](https://min.io/). You can run it locally by following the instructions described [here](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/).